# Linux: How do I make sure a driver is loaded? (Or force it to be loaded?)

Tags: linux, drivers, usb

I have a device that uses a chip that requires a specific USB driver. Supposedly it is in the Linux kernel after v5.5. I'm using a RPi with the 6.1.21-v8+ kernel, so the driver should be included. When I plug the device in, nothing shows up in /dev/. (I use `ls -lartR|cat -n|tail -n1` to count the number of devices.) Supposedly it shows up as a ttyxx device, but I don't see new ones when I plug this in.

I used lsusb and grep and the driver is not listed. How do I know if the driver is being loaded? Is it possible that even if it's "in the kernel," that it's not included in a base install? How can I make sure the kernel is in this particular distro or install image and that it's loaded?

For more reference, this is RasPiOS. I'm asking in the Unix & Linux section because I've had issues with it on a Linux non-Pi system and may have to use that system if there's something wrong with this one. The driver is Proflic USA's PL2303GL, which can be downloaded and built from [links on this page](https://prolificusa.com/product/pl2303gl-8-pin-usb-uart-bridge-controller/). It includes folders for building on kernels up to 5.4 (and I've tried building it - always get errors), but since it's included from 5.5 on, there's nothing for building it on newer kernels. The device I'm trying to connect to is a Netgate SG-1100, which is a pfSense firewall. I'm open to alternatives for doing this.

Comment: `lsusb` should list, just list, the device, with or without driver. If it doesn't show up, there is another problem. Don't `grep` the output, since it could be listed under another name. `sudo tail -f /var/log/kern.log` should also show *something* when you plug it in. Please add that to your question.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I've tried this in several Linux systems and tried multiple USB cables. I'm beginning to think the USB port on the device is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out kernel was built with support for this device by reading config.gz file in /proc

`zgrep USB_SERIAL_PL2303 /proc/config.gz`

some distros put kernel config in /boot directory

`grep USB_SERIAL_PL2303 /boot/config-*`

If module is present you can use `lsmod` command to view all loaded modules

also i suggest looking for information from `dmesg` output if previous steps failed.

Comment: Good points, but it turns out on RasPiOS, those aren't working. I finally got it to work (turns out FOUR "good" USB cables that have worked with other devices didn't work and the fifth cable did. But lsmod did not give me any indication the module I had was available. When I finally saw that dmesg didn't show any messages when I plugged it in, I started checking hardware. Still, with other distros, this could be useful. Do you have any idea where else the info in config.gz would be stored in various distros?

Comment: I found this question on stackexchange regarding this question https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119483/how-to-access-to-the-configuration-of-my-raspberry-pi-os-lite to get info about running kernel config, the places that i provided above should be enough to find config.gz, but i suggest looking at distro-specific documentation if it isn't present

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to check again, since it cites /proc/config.gz, but I could swear I didn't see that in /proc. I'm using RasPiOS and he's using the lite version, but he could be using an earlier version. Still, you'd think if it were in lite, it'd be in the full version.

Comment: have you tried inserting appropiate module as described from the link above?  (sudo modprobe configs)

Comment: That's part of the puzzle. I couldn't find a hint of the module with lsmod, but when I FiNALLY got the cable connection to work, it showed up with no issue - so the mod was there all along. (Apparently, and I'm not the first person to report this, the case for the device I was connecting to is a bit thick, so people have had to trim it or find other ways to get the connecter far enough in for proper contact - so my issue was kind of weird.)